# Finding the source of a supplication

Tags: source-identification, reference-request

Can anyone tell me the from which the following lines belong.. Ya Munazzilash Shafa’i Wa Muzh’hibad Da’i anzil ‘ala Maabi Min Da’inn Shafaa’ann’...thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The du'a you mentioned is referred to as a du'a made by 'Ali ibn Abi Taleb () in Shi'a sources such as Tib al-A'immah طب الأئمة  of ibn Sabur az-Zayyat ابن سابور الزيات (p.102 see [here](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1288_%D8%B7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%A6%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_102#top) in Arabic) and Bihar al-Anwar بحار الأنوار of [al-'Alamah al-Majlisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad-Baqer_Majlesi) العلامة المجلسي (Juz' 92 page 78 see [here](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1523_%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A9%D9%A2/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_80) in Arabic) as a remedy against a whole bunch of diseases such as leprosy, vitiligo and what is referred ti as the bad disease الداء الخبيث  (What ever that might be)

> وعنه صلوات الله عليه وآله أنه قال ضع يدك عليه وقل **يا منزل الشفاء ومذهب الداء انزل على ما بي من داء شفاء**.

So it is narrated that 'Ali ibn Abi Talib () recommended to put the hand on the place where the disease is located and recite these words:

> Ya Munnazila a-Shifa'a wa Mudhiba ad-Da' anzil 'ala ma bi min Da'in shifaa'an
>    <sub>My own translation take it carefully</sub>
>   Oh (Lord) who gives (descends) the healing and takes away the illness(es) give (descend) (on the) desease that has befallen me a healing

It appears also without the recommendation described above in al-Kafi (Juz' 2 page 567 see [here](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1123_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%AE-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A2/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_567) in Arabic) of [al-Kulayni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_Ya%27qub_al-Kulayni).

Answer (score 2):

يا منزل الشفاء ومذهب الداء انزل على ما بي من داء شفاء

It is not in the Holy Quran anywhere. It is from [al-kafi](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1123_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%AE-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A2/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_567): a shia book of hadith from the ahl-bayt.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a Du'a, but I can't recall one from what you have stated; however, I find some words from your quote that fit a specific Du'a and another that fit another Du'a.

### The First Possible Du'a:

Ayesha (R.A.) stated that when anyone among them had an illness, Prophet Mohammad (SAW.) used to rub the area of the pain reciting the following dua:

**In Arabic:**

> أَذْهِبِ الْبَأْسَ رَبَّ النَّاسِ وَاشْفِ أَنْتَ الشَّافِي لَا شِفَاءَ
>   إِلَّا شِفَاؤُكَ شِفَاءٌ لَا يُغَادِرُ سَقَمَاً

[Said in this way](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8oOOWtUniBw/maxresdefault.jpg):

> Alaahumma rabb-nnasi adhibil-ba'sa washfi wa antashafii laa shifaa' illaa shifaa'uk, shifaa' alla yughadiru saqama.

**The translation in English:**

> O Lord of the people, remove this pain and cure it, You are the one
>   who cures and there is no one besides You who can cure, grant such a
>   cure that no illness remains.

*(Bukhari, Muslim)*

It is a Du'a for curing of any illness.

---

**A Du'a from Qur'an** about the same topic is when the Islamic prophet Ayyub said:

[Surah Al-Anbya — Verse 83](https://quran.com/21/83-84), **in Arabic:**

> وَأَيُّوبَ إِذْ نَادَىٰ رَبَّهُ أَنِّي مَسَّنِيَ الضُّرُّ وَأَنتَ أَرْحَمُ الرَّاحِمِينَ

**Recited in this way:**

> An-nee mas-sa-ni-yaD-Dur-ru wa ‘AN-ta ‘Ar-Ha-mur-raa-Hi-meen.

**The translation in English:**

> Truly distress has seized me, but You are Most Merciful of those that
>   are merciful.

### The Second Possible Du'a:

Is a Dua' for supplication made against an enemy, **in Arabic:**

> اللَّهُمَّ مُنْزِلَ الكِتَابِ سَريعَ الحِسابِ اهْزِمَ الأَحْزَابَ اللَّهُمَّ اهْزِمْهُمْ وَزَلْزِلْهُمْ

**Said in this way:**

> Allahumma munzilal-kitab, sareeAAal-hisab, ihzimil-ahzab, allahummah-zimhum wazalzilhum.

**The translation in English:**

> O Allah, Revealer of the Book, Swift at reckoning, defeat the confederates. O Allah, defeat them and convulse them.

[Source for the 1st Du'a](https://www.searchtruth.com/dua/81/)

[Source for the 2nd Du'a](http://www.huda.tv/services/azkar/1185-supplication-made-against-an-enemy)